# What does "unsupported architecture" mean when loading app via Application Loader?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, application-loader

I'm using phonegap build service for our iOS application, (the app is built on HTML5), and the delivered ipa file from phonegap works fine using a development provisioning profile on our devices. However, when attempting to load the app to the app store (using a release provisioning profile for itunes), we get this from the application loader

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Unsupported Architectures. Your executable contains
>   unsupported architectures '[12-11]'." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset
>   (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

This happens for versions 2.8 and 2.9 of Application loader. We're using Phonegap build service 2.7, 2.9 and 3.0. How can we determine what the "unsupported architectures" are from PhonegapBuild ? is there a method for identifying what features we are using that may be contributing to this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to successfully upload the app. The issues was that I was running OSX 10.7.5 and running Application Loader 2.8 (AL), which seems to be compatible with Moutain Lion (10.8). Once upgrading to Mountain Lion you can do another update to 10.8.5 which will install Application Loader 2.9. (You can upgrade to 10.8 via the Apple=>"App Store" option on your Mac. It is a paid upgrade.)

If you downloaded the latest AL from the itunes connect portal and install it, it doesn't tell you that it's incompatible with older verions of Mac OSX before 10.8. All you'll get is an obscure message that your ipa is an "unsupported architecture" which in "Appleonean" means "You need to upgrade your version of OSX". Extremely misleading as it's nothing to do with your IPA, it's your OS. Even reading the PDF from Apple about AL there is no indication for minimum system requirements..

Answer (score 0):

same here - this app previously uploaded fine but when I try a support update I get this error along with a warning about a missing icon of 120px, 76px, and 152px

Comment: See my answer and try it. I'd like to confirm that it's as simple as upgrading the O/S on your Mac.

Comment: yeah I guess we both been posting in the same places :) - I've upvoted your answer, works great on 10.8.5 and AL 2.9 as confirmed over on the phonegap forums also.

Comment: Others are confirming on forums that this is the solution. A couple of exceptions but I don't know the variables in those cases. It's a big relief for us to have solved it. It was holding up real world business solutions. Happy to share :) In the realm of business software, an incompetent message like the one reported is an epic fail by Apple. Too many kids writing code in that place, no grown ups